# When a string is "" or a vector has no elements, is `begin()` equal to `end()`?

Tags: c++, string, iterator

When a `std::string` is `""` or a vector has no elements, is `begin()` equal to `end()`?

If so, what the value of `begin()`/`end()`?

Comment: How about compiling and checking it? about you second question, you don't care.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> When a std::string is "" or a vector has no elements, is begin() equal to end()?

Yes, for any empty standard library container, including `std::string` and `std::vector`, `begin()` will return the same iterator as `end()`.

> If so, what the value of begin()/end()?

It will be an iterator which is unique to that container, but should not be dereferenced.  Doing so would cause undefined behavior.

Comment: Why is it undefined instead of throwing an exception? efficiency?

Comment: @Elazar, Because "you pay for what you need" is a common sight in C++.

Comment: @Elezar exceptions aren't for programmer mistakes.

Comment: thanks, chris @Pubby (it's "elazar" BTW). so conceptually it should have been an `assert`, except the library is tuned to release mode and hence doesn't have asserts in it. Am I right? Or are there other gotcha's here?

Comment: @Elazar There are never `assert`s either.  If you are iterating through any container it is the responsibility of *your code* to check whether you have reached the `end()` iterator.  C++ will not check all your iterator dereferences to see if they're invalid.  It's assumed that *you're* checking.

Answer (score 4):

Yes.  Any STL container type with no elements will have `begin() == end()`, as the range of elements is the half-open range [`begin()`, `end()`).

Hope this helps!